# PK for each column

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

Is there a unique key associated to each column in a table?

I'm trying to give a column a unique key

I've looked at `user_tab_cols` and didn't see any.

See below sql.

```
select id
      (select c.column_id
       from user_tab_cols c
        where c.table_name = 'ABC'
         and c.column_name = 'CUST_QUESTION_ISSUES') AS q_id --this should be unique
from A
```

Comment: unique key != primary key. a primary key is always unique, but not every unique constraint is a primary key. there is no constraint on new columns by default. do you need every column to be unique on its own? it is not quite clear what you expect here

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Is it that you want `c.column_id` to be unique in that subquery? (the subquery itself in that main query is also nonsense). Perhaps just adding `DISTINCT` to your subquery will get you where you need to be? If not, please explain what you are trying to achieve without loading your question with terms like `PK` or `Unique Key` that are probably not the right wording for what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints (including unique key constraints) have a small performance impact, so by default they are not added to every column in the database - you have to manually choose which columns to add constraints to.

In your example, you can add a unique constraint to that column with:

```
ALTER TABLE abc
ADD CONSTRAINT uk_abc_issues UNIQUE (cust_question_issues);
```